# How to debug exception error: no function clause matching?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I keep getting an exception error while debugging an Erlang chat engine.

The error message reads:

```erlang
exception error: no function clause matching code_lock:locked(cast,
{button,1}, #{button => [], code => [a,b,c,d], length => 4})
```

Any idea how to debug that?

Answer (score 1):

The function `locked` is defined (the exception should also tell you in which while and on what line its definition starts), but none of the clauses matches the parameters shown in the exception.

For example, if we define

```
nfcm([H|T],X) ->
    [H,X|T];
nfcm({A,B},C) ->
    {A,C,B}.
```

We can call `nfcm([1,2,3], 4)` and `nfcm({1,2}, 3)` to get `[1,4,2,3]` and `{1,3,2}`, but calling `nfcm(1, 2)` or `nfcm({1,2,3}, 4)` leads to the exception, as `1` doesn't match neither a list nor a tuple, and `{1,2,3}` doesn't match a list either, and doesn't match a tuple of two elements.

There are two ways to solve the problem: either fix the definition of the function, or fix the parameters to match the existing definition.

Comment: Well, I did a tweak and ran a command code_lock:start_link([1,2,3], 4). And I got another ** exception error: undefined function code_lock:start_link/2.

Comment: Comments aren't the best place to paste code. It's better to update the question with the code.

Comment: Ok. 

I will update the question.  

Well, I did a tweak and ran a command code_lock:start_link([1,2,3], 4). And I got another ** exception error: undefined function code_lock:start_link/2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this had to do with the parameters to match the existing definition. Sorted it and the debugging process is ok.

Comment: Thanks @choroba for the hint.